# How can we evaluate a homomorphism in $\alpha$?

Tags: field-theory

Some confusion in homomorphism . My confusion given below marked in red line

[image]

My question is that how  can we evaluate a homomorphism in $\alpha$?

My attempt :  I was  thinking $f : L \rightarrow k[x]$ and $g : L \rightarrow k[x]$

How can we show that $f=g$ ?

Comment: The homomorphism is given by $e:k[x]\to L$, $e(f)=f(\alpha)$. One can show it is indeed a homomorphism of rings. It seems like there is a link you can click to learn more about the evaluation homomorphism if you’d like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They've chosen an unnecessarily awkward way to phrase it, but for any polynomial ring $k[x]$ and any element $\alpha\in k$, there is a homomorphism (not homeomorphism) $E_\alpha\colon k[x]\to k$ given by $E_\alpha(f(x)) = f(\alpha)$ for any $f(x)\in k[x]$. (It's a good exercise to verify that this is a ring homomorphism.)

It would be easier to understand if they'd just said "evaluate both sides at $x=\alpha$".

Comment: To their defense, many students seem to miss that evaluations are ring homomorphisms, so emphasizing this may have some educational value.

Comment: exactly @k.stm personally me also

Comment: Fair enough, but I would call Wikipedia's attempt a drive-by mention rather an effective emphasis :)

Comment: @GregMartin It did get the job done in the end!